# InfinitePagingView infinite loop in uiscrollview

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiscrollview, infinite-loop

I'm using an `InfinitePagingView` from [here](http://blog.blackwhale.at/tag/infinite-paging/).

I am searching for a way to modify the class so that the `InfinitePagingView` will be infinite to the left, too. As it is, it is only infinite when scrolling right.
Here is the [original class file](https://github.com/anka/bw_examples/blob/master/InfinitePaging/Classes/InfinitePagingView.m).

I added a variable `int pageCount;` which is set by the delegate to be the count of the available arrays.

But I don't have a clue how to go on now.

Please help me with it by giving  some tips.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?
modifying scrollViewDidScroll as follows lets me scroll both ways, atleast it appears to

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)sView
{
    CGFloat pageWidth = sView.frame.size.width;
    int page = floor((sView.contentOffset.x - pageWidth / 2) / pageWidth) + 1;
    if (scrollView.contentOffset.x<0) {
        [scrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(scrollView.frame.size.width, 0) animated:NO];
    }
    else {
    [self updateToPage:page];
    }
}
```